# change font size option for mobile web app?

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing an app with phonegap and i want to add text size option for users. but i want this text size change saves to app so when the user reopen the app the text size stays the same he/she choose the last time?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: well i use local storage and it does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at phonegap localstorage, it could be what you're looking for:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html

Alternatively you might want to write some kind of an user configuration file using the file api:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File